# How to disable Laravel registration after first user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-artisan

I want to disable Laravel registration in my app after the first user has signed up.

This  is what I tried.

```php
if(User::count() != 0) {
   Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
} else {
   Auth::routes();
}
```

It does work, however if you clone the repo and want to run commands like

> php artisan key:generate, php artisan migrate, ...

it obviously doesn't work because there is no users table just yet.

Do you guys have an idea of how to make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

in your registration page check

```
if (Users::count() > 1) {
    return redirect('/')
}
```

your users cannot sign in and your problem was be solved :D